# Unable to push in Git

Tags: git, push

I went through other similar questions extensively before ending up asking my own question on this.

I am beginning to learn Git and I tried something very simple. My objective was to create a repo in my local machine, clone it to a folder in my local machine. Make changes to files in the clone. Push the changes to the repo. Here is what I did:

1. I created a folder 'test' with 'hi.txt' in it.
2. I ran `git init` inside the folder 'test'
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "done"`
5. `cd ..`
6. `git clone test newTest`

I was able to see a newTest clone getting created with a .git folder inside and the hi.txt cloned from the repo.

Then I made changes to the hi.txt inside the clone and ran the below commands:

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "done"`

So far so good. Now when I try to push the changes to the repo 'test' folder, I get the following error:

```
    $ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 248 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsist
ent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to matc
h
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to

remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into

remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some

remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set

remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To c:/test
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'c:/test'
```

So where am I going wrong? Have I misunderstood something? Will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first "repo" you created is behaving as a working copy, i.e. a non bare repo.

Real repos, the ones you can push to, have no working copy in them. They just hold a reference to all commits in all branches.

To convert a normal repo into a bare repo

1. Open the repo in your file explorer
2. Make sure you're displaying hidden files (otherwise, you won't see the .git folder)
3. Remove everything **except for the .git folder**
4. Move everything inside the .git folder to the root
5. Remove the empty .git folder
6. Execute `git config --bool core.bare true`

Now you can push to your bare repo.

Edit: using the steps from your question

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
echo '0.0.1' > version.txt
git commit -a -m "version file"
```

Now you have a non-bare repo, with the structure

[image]

Let's turn it into a bare repo

```
mv .git ../  
rm *
mv ../.git .
mv .git/* .
rm -rf .git
git config --bool core.bare true
```

now you have a bare repo, and its contents are

[image]

if at some point you get the error `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` [just ignore it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ1vw.jpg).

Now you can clone it as you originally did

```
cd ..
git clone test newTest
touch index.html
git commit index.html -m "index file"
git push
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. If I am remove all the files in my repo then how can my clones get the files? Can a bare repo have files in it to begin with?

Comment: the files in the working copy are just a temporary manifestation of the references in the .git folder, that's why you can switch branches without losing your work. A bare repo doesn't have such files, but it still has the references which is what matters. And it has them in the root instead of having them in a .git folder.

Comment: sorry I could not get your previous comment. Actually it gets a bit difficult for me to get the hang of git without a simple working example of it. Can you please modify the steps in my question which will meet the objective stated in the question? It will be of great help.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? I hope it will be of help

Comment: Only change to your steps was `git push` should be `git push origin master`. Then it worked for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, yes, if you don't have a global push strategy then you should add origin and branch.

Comment: When I try to merge files instead of push, I get errors. How can I merge the file insted of pushing in this scenario.

Comment: Why do you need to merge? Are there  diverging changes in your local and in the upstream?

Comment: Lets say I have a bare repo. Two users have cloned this and working on some files common to both. If user 'A' psuhes his change and user 'B' pushes his change, then the file gets overridden. I would rather want to merge the version of both 'A' and 'B'

Comment: The file wouldn't get overriden unless one of the developers uses ```push -f```, and you shouldn't do that unless you're very sure you want to discard other people's commits. However, doing ```pull``` when there's diverging changes in the origin will trigger a merge action, and ask you to resolve conflicts if there is any.

Comment: thanks a lot for solving all my questions patiently!

Comment: No problem. I spent several weeks migrating my company's projects from svn to git and figuring things up by myself, so I kind of project that clueless me into people that are starting their ways in git.